# Why doesn't my text field with 'Email Address' content type suggest emails?

Tags: ios, uitextfield, uistackview, autofill

I have two `UITextField` fields on a sign in page in my app, one for an email address and one for a password. The two text fields are in a `UIStackView`. I have the email field content type set to "Email Address" and the password field content type set to "Password" and secure text entry. When I click on the email text field, the suggestion is for a password.

When I don't set a content type for the password, and I don't secure the text entry, the email address text field works as it should and suggests email addresses.

**UPDATE:**
Email autofill works when I remove the fields from `UIStackView`.

How can I secure the text entry of the password and have the email address field suggest emails without removing it from the `UIStackView`?

[image: Screenshot of Email field suggesting password]

Here is a link to test files that cause this issue: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1CdhuRMvNcMTR2Ijwl7vZilpIL_wY6tUj/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Code and screenshots will get more eyeballs on your question

Comment: I think this is a legitimate obscure xcode issue. We had the same issue with an email and password custom UITextField embedded within a stackview. Our workaround was to set the password (textContentType=.none & isSecureTextEntry=false) during init. Then in textFieldShouldBeginEditing() set (textContentType=.password & isSecureTextEntry=true) when the password field is touched. This enables the email field to suggest emails the first time and then makes the password field secure prior to editing. After a password field is made secure, the email suggestions stop working again.

Answer (score 1):

Can't reproduce any such issue. You didn't give much description, but I get the idea we have two text fields in a stack view, one for password, the other for email address. I created an app like that.

[image]

I ran the app.

I tapped in the password field and was prompted for a password.

[image]

I tapped in the email field and was offered two email addresses.

[image]

Could it be that you're just confused about what text field is which? Maybe you have more text fields than you think, or one is overlaying another?

Comment: Sorry for the lack of description. Honestly didn’t know what else to say other than that the content types aren’t working as they should. Both fields are part of a custom IBDesignable class and set as text field delegates. I took off the class and unset delegates and nothing changed. Only thing that worked was unembedding. Will try just deleting them all and recreating the page.

Comment: I will look more into it tomorrow and let you know what I figure out. Thanks for the suggestions!

Comment: Why not try to reproduce the issue in a project we can download and see for ourselves? I mean, look, I've gone the extra mile and created a project and taken screen shots and proved it's set up as you describe and it's working; you haven't done anything at all to share with us.

Comment: I have linked the files and provided a screenshot of the issue